# Azure functions throws "An error occurred while sending the request" for some of my customers

Tags: c#, azure-functions

All Azure functions work fine in "MySoftware 2.0.14". I had to redeploy all azure functions and change the addresses in the software and release the new version "MySoftware 2.0.18". Everything worked good but for about 3-10% of my customers stopped working all functions.

I had a TeamViewer session with a lot of these guys and the functions behave like they just don't exist. Like when I change the function address to some random string. It is in both cases throws "An error occurred while sending the request."

The full exception of these guys:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at (TaskAwaiter`1& )
   at InstaGTO.Model.ServerCommunication.ServerRequest.♶┩♼﵆⚝┚⚶╇╽♅⚢▚♋﷜⛴﷖╬♽⛣⚒⚧﷈⛍▄￱☽▄┢﷪┒▷◔┪╨⚿﷟♻䷪♩☈☯╃䷃╓⚨⚾♠◪▒☦☔┻￺╩﷾⛿﵏┅╰䷚▊┸◞䷠￸⛂◑♑┾╲◟⚇♞╇┈﯃◢﷚╳│⛖☃☲┼◩▼◢﵅◨█┕﷮╄⚞┨◤◊⛣┦.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at (TaskAwaiter`1& )
   at InstaGTO.ViewModel.RegistrationViewModel.◮☶╞☿﷧┿䷯⚥╻╋﮻♭┣▣╖⚇☢﯀☼￳☝♐﯃⛔⚇﷎☗⛤☣﵂䷤䷦◥╱▩⛃╷⚒﷑▉⚫▇⚓⚺◻▒♓╥䷹║♀●═╺䷚䷵䷲﯈䷾﷬┞☍♶⛎﷡◜▚♥◕♒┉☬▌▀⚻䷜☸◿▫﷚◶⚀├▹⛼╢┤⛤╄⚚♔⛲◱♬╲★￴◷┸.MoveNext()
```

I didn't make any changes in the functions neither in the code. I just only deploy them on the new Azure plan and change addresses in the software. I really don't understand why it doesn't work for someone. The insights didn't notice any error but my software just doesn't work for those guys because they cannot sign up, cannot request a new password, register and all stuff on the cloud.

Comment: From your error message - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3665

Comment: did you solve this

Comment: I ll try it when Im home

Comment: Yes, it works. SSL changed to 1.0 and it started to work for these guys. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Hari, Following https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3665 and SSL changed to 1.0 did solve the issue.

Comment: Could've been my answer :p